# Where do I download eclipse kepler for php

Tags: php, eclipse

I don't know why I'm having so much trouble installing eclipse kelpler for php. All I can find is the Java package at http://www.eclipse.org/downloads

I downloaded 4.3 Java version, where do I go to add PHP? I am trying help install new software, but I don't know what URL to use.

ah yes, for windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For Eclipse Kepler currently you need PDT 3.2
Repository location: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.2/release